# Gradle custom task implementation: could not find method for arguments

Tags: gradle, groovy, gradle-task

I have an encryption task that receives an input file and an output file along with the key to perform encryption against. The strange thing is that when I try in extract a method that performs a line encryption and receives it as an argument, I get the next error: `Could not find method encryptLine() for arguments [PK] on task ':presentation:encryptScenarios' of type EncryptionTask.`.
When I inline this method - it works ok.

Here is a code of the inlined variant:

```
@TaskAction
void encryptFile() {
    assertThatEncryptionKeyIsPresent()
    createNewOutputFileIfNotExists()
    final FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)
    inputFile.eachLine { String line ->
        final byte[] inputBytes = line.getBytes()
        final byte[] secretBytes = key.getBytes()
        final byte[] outputBytes = new byte[inputBytes.length]
        int spos = 0
        for (int pos = 0; pos < inputBytes.length; ++pos) {
            outputBytes[pos] = (byte) (inputBytes[pos] ^ secretBytes[spos])
            spos += 1
            if (spos >= secretBytes.length) {
                spos = 0
            }
        }
        outputStream.write(Base64.encodeBase64String(outputBytes).getBytes())
    }
}
```

And here is the code of the extracted method variant:

```
@TaskAction
void encryptFile() {
    assertThatEncryptionKeyIsPresent()
    createNewOutputFileIfNotExists()
    final FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)
    inputFile.eachLine { String line ->
        byte[] outputBytes = encryptLine(line)
        outputStream.write(Base64.encodeBase64String(outputBytes).getBytes())
    }
}

private byte[] encryptLine(String line) {
    final byte[] inputBytes = line.getBytes()
    final byte[] secretBytes = key.getBytes()
    final byte[] outputBytes = new byte[inputBytes.length]
    int spos = 0
    for (int pos = 0; pos < inputBytes.length; ++pos) {
        outputBytes[pos] = (byte) (inputBytes[pos] ^ secretBytes[spos])
        spos += 1
        if (spos >= secretBytes.length) {
            spos = 0
        }
    }
    outputBytes
}
```

How to resolve this issue using this private method that encrypts a line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error seems to be connected to a Groovy issue referenced here : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7797

You are trying to call a private method from a closure within the same class and it looks like this is not supported.

Please try to remove the `private` modifier from `encryptLine` method definition, and you should get rid of this error.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it